# how to run (start) people detection / tracking (wg_perception) on hydro or indigo?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, tracking, ros-indigo, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I correctly run (start, launch, execute) people tracking (detection) package (wg_perception) on Hydro or Inidigo? What command sequence? I could not find any documentation for it. "roslaunch face_detector face_detector.rgbd.launch" does not enable me to see any visualizations in RViz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196624/how-to-run-(start)-people-detection-/-tracking-(wg_perception)-on-hydro-or-indigo?/) by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-11-04**:
The key question is how do you want to run people detection? There are separate algorithms for Kinect specific detection, face detection and leg detection.

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-07**:
roslaunch face_detector face_detector.rgbd.launch produces topics: /face_detector: cancel, faces_cloud, feedback, goal, people_tracker_measurements_array, result, status but PointCloud, in RViz, has no image (topic /face_detector/faces_cloud). How do I view image with rectangles around face?

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-07**:
Also: [INFO]: Constructing FaceDetector: "You must subscribe to one of FaceDetector's outbound topics or else it will not publish anything." And then, "process has finished cleanly. You have unsubscribed to FaceDetector's outbound topics, so it will no longer publish anything."  ?????

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-15**:
I figured out why the package might not be working. Package has dependencies: bfl, costmap_2d, and easy_markers. I was able to "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-bfl", and "ros-indigo-costmap-2d", but there was no easy_markers for Indigo. (continues in next message)

**Comment by [ROS_Portland_State_University_Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20663/ros_portland_state_university_robot/) on 2014-11-15**:
(continues): Out of desperation, I installed easy_markers from wu_ros_tools_hydro, and entire People Traker compiled but this seems to be the reason why it does not work. I posted separate request for ros-indigo-easy-markers

**Comment by [Pinchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10766/pinchi/) on 2015-06-07**:
I'm having the same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would focus on the face_detector package, and ignore the general people_tracking_filter package.

Use the documentation of [face_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector) and the rqt_graph package to make sure your topics line up.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0